# Plotly annotations show 'NaN' when passing text

Tags: plotly, annotations, bar-chart, customization

I want to create a graph with 2 charts:

- the first one shows the bank lending volumes by industry in Ukraine,
- the second one should show the market share of the biggest lender.

The underlying data looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQZ0t.png)

> {'Industry_eng': {Timestamp('2022-11-30 00:00:00'): 'Wholesale trade, except of motor vehicles and motorcycles'},
> 'perf_balance_sum': {Timestamp('2022-11-30 00:00:00'): 115.74671929402},
> 'top_lender_market_share': {Timestamp('2022-11-30 00:00:00'): 14.943532331454707},
> 'top_lender': {Timestamp('2022-11-30 00:00:00'): 'Ощадбанк'},
> 'top_lender_name_market_share': {Timestamp('2022-11-30 00:00:00'): 'Ощадбанк: 14.9'}}

So far, so good. The problem starts however, when I want to annotate the bars of the second chart with the last column from the dataframe (string with name and market share of the biggest lender by industry). Then it shows "NaN" as annotations. See here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqoO1.png)

This is the code. Any ideas? Many thanks for your help in advance!

```
# set subplot parameters

fig = make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 2, column_widths=[2, 1],
                    subplot_titles=('Performing loans volume',"     Market share"),
                    shared_yaxes=True, horizontal_spacing = 0.02)


# add data structures

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df['perf_balance_sum'], y = df['Industry_eng'], orientation = 'h',
                     text =  df['perf_balance_sum'], name = 'Market perf loans', marker = dict(color='steelblue'),
                    textfont=dict(size=11, family='Amalia', color='black')))
        


# WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK!!!!!! i want to show the value from df['top_lender_name_market_share'] within the bar showing the df['top_lender_market_share']
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df['top_lender_market_share'], y = df['Industry_eng'], orientation = 'h',
                     text = df['top_lender_name_market_share'], name  = 'top ms',), col = 2, row = 1)


# add layout structures

#general layout and titles
fig.update_layout(title = 'Lending by industry as of {}',
                  title_font_size = 16, title_font_family="Amalia", title_font_color="blue",
                  font_family="Amalia", font_color="black", font_size=11,
                  legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.5, xanchor="left", x=0.2, bgcolor=None),
                  legend_title_font_color="black",
                  height = 600, width = 1100,
                  barmode = 'overlay', yaxis=dict(type = 'category', categoryorder = 'trace'))

# add/format labels
fig.update_xaxes(row = 1, col = 1, title_text = 'Performing loans in UAH bn', title_font=dict(size=13, family='Amalia', color='black'), tickfont=dict(family='Amalia', color='darkblue', size=11), range=[0,160])
fig.update_xaxes(row = 1, col = 2, title_text = 'Top ms %', title_font=dict(size=13, family='Amalia', color='black'), tickfont=dict(family='Amalia', color='darkblue', size=11), range=[0,50])

fig.update_yaxes(row = 1, col = 1, title_text = "Industry", title_font=dict(size=13, family='Amalia', color='black'), tickfont=dict(family='Amalia', color='darkblue', size=11))
fig.update_yaxes(row = 1, col = 2, title_text = None, tickfont=dict(family='Amalia', color='darkblue', size=11))


# format annotation in bars
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:1.1f}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:1.1f}', col = 2, textposition='inside')
fig.update_annotations(font_size=14)

#deactivate legend for the two right subplots
for trace in fig['data']:
    if trace['name'] in ['raif ms', 'top ms']:
        trace['showlegend'] = False

fig.show()
```

I tried different things, such as

- passing a single figure to the text parameter, either as string or as a number Both works
- passing letters to the text parameter -> doesn't work. this is already pretty strange
- passing any other numeric column to the text parameter - works
- passing any non-numeric column - doesn't work
- turning the desired dataframe column into a list and passing that list to the text parameter - doesnt work

Is it possible that the annotations in GO bar charts for some reason accept only numeric values? but if so, why does "text = str(1)" work?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for being detailed in your question! my guess would be that it has to do with the characters in the `top_lender_name_market_share` column – it would be helpful if you could share a text sample of your dataframe (instead of an image) so that we can copy it and reproduce your error. you can do that by copying and pasting the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` directly into your question

Comment: With only the data and code provided, if I had to guess, I would say that the following lines seem to be affected, so why don't you try disabling them? `fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:1.1f}', col = 2, textposition='inside')` Or perhaps you do not need a template for the numerical display of this line.

Comment: Is the annotation column in the second graph a concatenation of strings and numbers? If so, the numeric portion needs to be split.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! Good idea to deactivate the "fig.update_traces..." line. Unfortunately this didn't help. The annotation column is the result of merging a string column (bank name) and a numeric column (market share) but the latter was turned into a string when merging:     `df['top_lender_name_market_share'] = df['top_lender'] + ': ' + df['top_lender_market_share'].apply(lambda x: '{:.1f}'.format(x)).astype(str)`

Comment: I see that you are applying numeric formatting to a column of string annotations. I ran your code from the updated data. By modifying your code to the following, the annotations will be displayed correctly. I am splitting the string column and annotating with the second value. `fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df['top_lender_market_share'], y = df['Industry_eng'], orientation = 'h', text = df['top_lender_name_market_share'].str.split(': ', expand=True)[1], name  = 'top ms',), col = 2, row = 1)`

Comment: Thank you for this hint, unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue really. By using the second part of the split string [1], it shows only the market share. I could take that as well from the df['top_lender_market_share'] column. But my problem is that I want to show the name of the bank, and the market share. therefore I created the column df['top_lender_name_market_share'] - but I don't manage to show the string as annotation...

Comment: I just found the solution myself (but only because your proposals guided me in the right direction - so thanks a lot!!!): The problem was that I deactivated the fig.update_traces command that referred to the col = 2, but not the line before. So the solution is that I mention explicitly the columns for which the trace format should be updated. Again, many thanks!